# Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass `aliases: true` to `Psych::load` or `Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm upgrading a Rails app, but, when I try to launch the server it says:
`Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass` aliases: true`to`Psych::load`or`Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)`
This is the trace:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.8 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:432:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass `aliases: true` to `Psych::load` or `Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:347:in `block in revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each_slice'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:169:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:347:in `block in revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `each_slice'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:345:in `revive_hash'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:169:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:320:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych.rb:334:in `safe_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych.rb:369:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:217:in `input_to_output'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:233:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:233:in `load_file'
    from /home/andres/Escritorio/projects/vemon-gem/lib/vemon/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /home/andres/Escritorio/projects/vebase/config/environment.rb:8:in `<main>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /home/andres/Escritorio/projects/vebase/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My enviroment.rb has::

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# load private data
PRIVATE_DATA = YAML.safe_load(ERB.new(File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/private.yml").read).result, aliases: true)[Rails.env]

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

This is my enviroment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative "application"

# load private data
PRIVATE_DATA = YAML.safe_load(ERB.new(File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/private.yml").read).result, aliases: true)[Rails.env]

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

And this is my private.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
    secret_token: 'f322344234223432fdasasad'
    secret_key: '2ffadsfdsfdsfsdsdffsd12'
    url_host: 'localhost:3000'
    mailer_address: 'mail.example.com'
    mailer_port: 34
    mailer_domain: 'example.com'
    quality_responsive_mail: 'contacto@example.com'

development:
    <<: *defaults


test:
    <<: *defaults

production:
    <<: *defaults
```

EDIT:
The project use a gem from my company called Vemon and here is calling a load_file without an aliases: true:

```
module Vemon
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Vemon

    initializer 'vemon.start' do |app|
      # do not run on console or generator
      unless defined?(Rails::Console)

        # read configuration
        config_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'vemon.yml')
        config = YAML::load_file(config_file)[Rails.env]
        if config['enabled']
          Agent.instance.start(config)
        else
          Rails.logger.warn('Vemon') { 'Vemon installed but disabled in configuration!' }
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

But its a gem that i dont have access to¿Maybe is this what is causing the issue?Seeing the traces i see that is getting called.¿Is it the cause of the problem?
from /home/andres/Escritorio/projects/vemon-gem/lib/vemon/engine.rb:11:in `block in class:Engine'
If I comment the initialize line it says

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.8 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:79:in `log_to_stdout': undefined method `formatter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

        console.formatter = Rails.logger.formatter
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /home/andres/Escritorio/projects/vebase/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyone has any clue why is this happening?

Comment: which Psych version are you using?

Comment: When I use bundle show psych it says:
Could not find gem 'psych'.
I'm using ruby 3.2.2 and didnt added nothing referenced to that. I't works good before the upgrading

Comment: It's flagging line 8 of environment.rb, which is your `initialize!` call. I suspect you're looking at the wrong thing with your private.yml line. Try removing that line and see if the problem still happens, I think it's some other yaml loading that's triggering the issue.

Comment: Rails 7 now ships with psych version 4 which makes YAML.load default to safe mode did you try loading the YAML file with unsafe_load? you could also check these issues they are related to the problem you are facing: 
https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5140
https://github.com/chrisftw/fast_config/issues/1

Comment: unsafe_load give the same error of:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:432:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass `aliases: true` to `Psych::load` or `Psych::safe_load`. (Psych::AliasesNotEnabled)